# Laravel foreach not working into my product multiiple discount model?

Tags: laravel

I have build discount system based on product and user id, I have almost done everything i just got error in my laravel model bellow my code:
public static function discount($p_id)
{

```
    $discount = Discount::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id )->first();
    
    $p = Product::where('id', $p_id)->first();

    $multidiscount =  MultipleDiscount::where('user_id','like','%'.trim(Auth::user()->id).'%')->with('typeItems')->first();

    $orderdetail = MultiDiscountType::where('multidiscount_id',$multidiscount->id)->pluck('value');        
    if( !is_null($multidiscount) || is_null($discount) ){
        foreach ($multidiscount->typeItems as $key => $mdiscount) {
            # code...
            $discprice = explode(',', $orderdetail);
            if( $discount->value <= $mdiscount->value ){
                if( $mdiscount->type == 'percentage' ){
                    $p_val = $p->price / 100 * $mdiscount->value ;
                    $p_price = $p->price - $p_val;
                }
            }else{
                if( $discount->type == 'percentage' ){
                    $p_val = $p->price / 100 * $discount->value;
                    $p_price = $p->price - $p_val;
                }
                else {
                    $p_val = $p->price - $discount->value;
                    $p_price = $p_val;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        $p_price = $p->price;
    }

    return $p_price;

}
```

I got nice result in my product blade view file but issue with in my multidiscount table have two rows but i get only last row value. Whats is the wrong i dont know bellow multiplediscount table structure:

```
Multi Discount Table:
|id|     name   |status |user_id|
|1 |Black Friday| active| 2, 3  |
```

I used repeater field for multiple discount based on product and user.

```
Multi Discount Table Item
    |id|  product it  |value|discount_id|
    |1 |   3          |  25 |    1      |
    |2 |   2          |  20 |    1      |
```

Comment: Not really the solution to your problem, but using LIKE to find by user_id is not correct. User ID 1 will also load the discounts for user id 11. You should use a pivot table and belongsToMany relation, or at least a JSON column

Comment: user_id checking and its workig fine, it was build by other developer, I am currently facing issue with the query in my product model.

Comment: I am 100% sure it does not work as intended. it will work fine as long as there is no user ID > 9. When there is a user with ID 10, User with ID 1 will get the discounts from user id 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `get()` instead of `first()` in your MultipleDiscount module to fetch all records:

```
$multidiscount =  MultipleDiscount::where('user_id','like','%'.trim(Auth::user()->id).'%')->with('typeItems')->get();
```

Although I'm not sure why you are fetching the discounts for a specific user with the `LIKE` clause. For example, if you have a user with the ID of 10, this will return values for the users with the ID that somehow contains 10 like 1101, 1210212, ... and so on.

EDIT:

```
foreach ($multidiscount as $key => $mdiscount) {
    # code...
    $discprice = explode(',', $orderdetail);
    if( $discount->value <= $mdiscount->typeItems->value ){
        if( $mdiscount->typeItems->type == 'percentage' ){
            $p_val = $p->price / 100 * $mdiscount->typeItems->value ;
            $p_price = $p->price - $p_val;
        }
    }else{
        if( $discount->type == 'percentage' ){
            $p_val = $p->price / 100 * $discount->value;
            $p_price = $p->price - $p_val;
        }
        else {
            $p_val = $p->price - $discount->value;
            $p_price = $p_val;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using [like] because of client want that way, and I used as you said [get] method I still get last row of the table. but there should be come two rows who belongs that user and discounts.

Comment: Do you have more than one typeItems? Because this iterates the $multidiscount->typeItems. If you want to fetch all discounts you may want to loop through $multidiscount and then fetch the typeitems per each.

Comment: yes i did loop, but still same, let me show you screenshot here: https://prnt.sc/mKXrdIaN3Uh8

Comment: Try the edited part of the answer to see if it helps.

Comment: alrights, let me try it man

Comment: https://prnt.sc/JC4_vuA8nykG, Please see the screenshot

Comment: You are trying to multiply the array of $discprice by 100. The multiplication should be between 2 numbers. Not number and array. $p_val = $p->price / 100 * $discprice.

Comment: I dont understand, but yes this is the issue, I have pvot table where i add multiple product discount value, example one product for discount 20% antoher product discount 16%.. based on assign user. So when user login they will see offer price underneath product title. but the issue came is if i add two product for same user with different discount i got last discount value and my query showing price based on last discount value.

Comment: Do you understand what I meant?

Comment: In $orderdetail you pluck all the "value" and then you create an array in "$discprice = explode(',', $orderdetail);". Then you try to use the array in the multiplication operation. That is not possible. If you want to return an array of pricing, you need to loop through $discprice and then do the multiplication based on values.

Comment: ok ok let me try with loop

Comment: bye the way can you edit the your code??

Comment: BTW, the $orderdetail returns an array with PLUCK. You do not need to use the expload

Comment: yes I thought same things, but at end of the day it returns last row value. not all.

Comment: Would you be able to dd($multidiscount) right after the $multidiscount? so we can see what records it returns?

Comment: here is screenshoot: https://prnt.sc/WO6tUiCip9LH

Comment: did you, check the screenshooty, any luck???

Comment: Change the ->first() to ->get() and do dd($multidiscount) where you put the return to see how many records it returns. I would suggest going to MySQL and selecting the same filter and see if you get more than one row. for example "SELECT * FROM multidiscounts WHERE user_id like '%2%'" (or any other user id). Other than that, there is no reason for not getting all the rows matching your filter here.

Comment: ok let me try it

Comment: Hey man, I am very near to fix this things, if i can fix it i will mark correct answer of your question. Can you please take a look my screenshot onemore time here: https://prnt.sc/HgaKliIfEGv8 
Now I want to show only value, how can i do this??

Comment: I'm would be happy if I can help but what value from what? I can't see anything in your screenshot.  I need more explanation.